# Bluetooth printer prints garbage character for every new object

Tags: android, printing

I am taking reference of [P25 Demo Example](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/P25Demo) to print my receipt using Bluetooth printer.

Everything works fine. It's printing receipt also in defined format. But the problem is for every new String and StringBuilder object its printing few garbage characters.

Below I am adding my function:-

```
private void printStruk() {
    String titleStr = "Receipt" + "\n\n";

    StringBuilder contentSb = new StringBuilder();

    contentSb.append("IDPEL     : 435353535435353" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("NAMA      : LORENSIUS WLT" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("TRF/DAYA  : 50/12244 VA" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("BL/TH     : 02/14" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("ST/MTR    : 0293232" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("RP TAG    : Rp. 100.000" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("JPA REF   :" + "\n");

    StringBuilder content2Sb = new StringBuilder();

    content2Sb.append("ADM BANK  : Rp. 1.600" + "\n");
    content2Sb.append("RP BAYAR  : Rp. 101.600,00" + "\n");


    byte[] titleByte    = Printer.printfont(titleStr, FontDefine.FONT_24PX,FontDefine.Align_CENTER, 
                            (byte)0x1A, PocketPos.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);

    byte[] content1Byte = Printer.printfont(contentSb.toString(), FontDefine.FONT_24PX,FontDefine.Align_LEFT, 
                            (byte)0x1A, PocketPos.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);


    byte[] content2Byte = Printer.printfont(content2Sb.toString(), FontDefine.FONT_24PX,FontDefine.Align_LEFT,  
                            (byte)0x1A, PocketPos.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);

    byte[] totalByte    = new byte[titleByte.length + content1Byte.length +content2Byte.length];


    int offset = 0;
    System.arraycopy(titleByte, 0, totalByte, offset, titleByte.length);
    offset += titleByte.length;

    System.arraycopy(content1Byte, 0, totalByte, offset, content1Byte.length);
    offset += content1Byte.length;

    System.arraycopy(content2Byte, 0, totalByte, offset, content2Byte.length);
    offset += content2Byte.length;

    byte[] senddata = PocketPos.FramePack(PocketPos.FRAME_TOF_PRINT, totalByte, 0, totalByte.length);

    sendData(senddata); 
}
```

In above code, it's printing Title String *Receipt* in center of the paper,but before that it also print some garbage character.

Comment: it may be that BT Printer not supported or wrong formatted. For my case PrintCube PCII not supported image and Rongta BT Printer supported using the same code.. BTW Rongta have SDK

Comment: @ZeroOne Is there any global SDK you know which supports all bluetooth printer, because I can not restrict user to use only specific company's 
 bluetooth printer.

Comment: BT Printer use the same output format which using java output stream.. thats is depends on the printer it self which support the encoding or not.. try googling code for BT Thermal Printer.. it can be use to any BT printer

Comment: @Anil Ghodake,I am also facing same problem, Did you solved that problem ?

Comment: @KCN Not yet, For now I have used **btsdk.jar**  which is worked for my printers